# What does % mean when typing in a file path?

Tags: batch-file

An example could be `%APP_LOCAL%\default` or `%APP_BASE%`.

Comment: It's a variable that gets expanded. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html

Comment: I believe that comes from MS-DOS. It indicates that what is between both '%' is a variable name. For exemple, the variable %TMP% has as a value "C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Temp".

Comment: You're quite lazy - a single Google search will show you the result: http://superuser.com/questions/632891/what-is-appdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Batch / the command-line variables are signed for later expansion with enclosing them in percentage signs. There are exceptions which are irrelevant for your question though.
The ones asked by you are environment variables that are set by your system and most likely contain paths or parts of a path.